# $O_{P}$ notation and Consistent estimators

Tags: estimators, consistency

What is meant by $\hat{Y} - Y=O_{P}(n^{-1})$, for example, and how this is related to consistent estimators?

Comment: You'll have to say more about what $\hat{Y}$ is in this context.

Comment: I want to understand the different between those two so I think of $Y$ to be some random variable that I estimate.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the difference between $\hat Y$ and $Y$ is bounded in probability even after dividing by $n^{-1}$ (i.e., even after multiplying by $n$), see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation).

If $\hat Y$ is an estimator of $Y$ (you should indeed be more precise here), then $\hat Y$ is indeed consistent for $Y$, because if something remains bounded even after multiplying it by something which diverges (like $n$), then that something must go to zero (in probability).

Here, that something is $\hat Y -Y$ and $n(\hat Y -Y)$ being bounded as $n\to\infty$ means that $\hat Y -Y$ goes to zero, which is another way of saying that $\hat Y$ converges in probaility to, or is consistent for, $Y$.

Comment: Nice answer (+1)! This implies that $n^{\alpha}(\hat Y-Y)$ converges to $0$ in probability for any $\alpha<1$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you could write $n^\alpha(\hat Y -Y)$ as $n^{\alpha-1}\cdot n(\hat Y -Y)$, where the second term $n(\hat Y -Y)$ is bounded ($O_P(1)$) by assumption. The first, $n^{\alpha-1}$ tends to zero for $\alpha<1$, so that the product of something bounded and something which goes to zero also goes to zero.

Comment: Are you saying that in the case of a consistent estimator one can have the relation if $O_{P}$ then $o_{P}$. The definitions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation) say that if $o_{P}$ then $O_{P}$ holds always.

Comment: I did not say that in general, no, only for entries in big-Oh that tend to zero.